# Displaying an array of objects in React native using map method

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

I have following component where I want to display data from an API, ShopScreen.js. I retrieve data with useEffect hook from API in service folder, and everything is ok, the json data is being loaded into data variable from useState hook, when I console.log it.
I have problem to the display data from this variable with map method. I get the error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. Can spot somebody where the problem is?
ShopScreen.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import { fetchShops } from '../services/fetchShops';

const ShopsScreen = props => {
    const [data, setShops] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchShops()
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setShops(data));
    }, []);

    return(
        <View>
            <Text>The Shops Screen!</Text>
                {data.result.map(shop => {return (<Text>{shop.address}</Text>)})}
        </View>
    );
};

export default ShopsScreen;
```

My service for fetching data is fetchShops.js

```
export const fetchShops = () => {
    const URL = `https://vilvumbiyl.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Dev/store/MEBD/list`;
    return fetch(URL)
}
```

Comment: Try something like this ```{data.result && data.result.map(shop => {return (<Text>{shop.address}</Text>)})}```

Comment: Sajeeb Ahamed what means this?

Comment: Check it the ```data.result``` is available or not before using map.

Comment: Aha because of asynchronous call. I first time see this syntax. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useEffect` without any params is equal to `componentDidMount` and for this reason, is called after the render.

So, the first time your jsx code is called, `data.result.map` is undefined and only after the re-render, do to the response of `fetchShops()`, it has a value.

You simply need to check the value like this:

`data.result && data.result.map()`

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
const [data, setShops] = useState({result : {}});
```

or test `data.result` before use map on it.

`ShopsScreen` returns your view(JSX) before you get answer from your rest API. The result is `null`. You get the exception.